# How to implement dijit in EPiServer 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dojo, episerver

I've been trying to implement widgets with Dojos Dijit in EPiServer 7. I know how dojo/dijit works, but how do I implement it in EPiServer CMS 7? The project I have is a MVC project. I've tried looking at this guide (http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Linus-Ekstrom/Dates/2012/10/Creating-a-Dojo-based-component/), but I can't find the namespaces which he is using in his C# class. I've tried to find other tutorials, but I have had little luck.

Does anyone know how to do this or can link me to a tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the same question on EPiServers forums and figured it out.

What was wrong was the data in the WidgetType property.

```
[Component(
    PlugInAreas = "/episerver/cms/assets",
    Categories = "cms",
    WidgetType = "mycomponents.testModule", //was wrong, I had to define "mycomponents".
    Title = "test component",
    Description = "A componenet")]
public class testModuleComponent
{
}
```

I had to define a namespace that dojo would recognize. I did this in module.config. This is my module.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<module>
  <dojoModules>
    <add name="mycomponents" path="~/ClientResources/Scripts" />
  </dojoModules>
</module>
```

Scripts is the folder with the dojo script. I define ~/ClientResources/Scripts as root of a namespace with the name mycomponents.

EPiServer automatically includes dojo for you, so you dont have to do it yourself.

See this thread: 
http://world.episerver.com/Modules/Forum/Pages/thread.aspx?id=63255&pageIndex=1#reply.